# Distribution for dependent event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm struggling with this question:

For three events $A, B, C$, we know that $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B)=\mathbb{P}(C)=p$.
Let $X$ be the number of events that occurred among the three.
What is the distribution of $X$ when every two events are foreign to each other?

I hope I use the right term, I mean that the events have no connection to each other. 
I think that only one of them can occur in each iteration, but I also try to figure out what is the probabilty when non of them occurs.

Comment: "Foreign to each other" tells me that they are independent. What is dependent then?

Comment: If the events are independent as @zoli suspects, the distribution is binomial.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what "foreign to each other" means. I'm reasonably sure from your comment that you mean for "the events to have no connection to each other" that you mean for them to be *independent*. We actually have to assume something slightly stronger; we need to assume that $A, B, C$ are all *mutually independent* as a group of 3, not just that each pair of them is independent. (If all we know is that each pair is independent, then the question in fact cannot be answered.)

So, proceeding from the assumption that you meant for all three of the events to be mutually independent, let's think about what the distribution of $X$ could be. Note that $X$ can be four different things: $0$, $1$, $2$, and $3$. Let's start with $X = 3$, which is the easiest; the events are independent, so $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) P(B) P(C) = p^3$. (Exercise: what's the probability that $0$ of them occur?)

Next, let's look at the case where $X = 1$. There are three ways for this to happen; either we can have only $A$ occur, or only $B$ occur, or only $C$ occur. By independence, the probability of only $A$ occurring is
$$P(A \cap B^c \cap C^c) = P(A) P(B^c) P(C^c) = p(1-p)(1-p) = p(1-p)^2.$$
The calculation is the same for having "only $B$ occur" and "only $C$ occur," so the total probability of $X = 1$ is $3 \cdot p(1-p)^2$. (Exercise: what's the probability that exactly $2$ of them occur?)

Collectively, all the above provides the distribution for $X$. As ChargeShivers pointed out in the comments, $X$ is an example of a [binomial random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), but I think it's instructive to compute this directly when the number of events is small ($n = 3$).

$$\rule{6cm}{0.02cm}$$

However, I also wonder whether the events are intended to be *mutually exclusive*, which would be the most natural interpretation of "foreign to each other" in my mind. This would mean that $A \cap B = A \cap C = B \cap C = \emptyset$, or that they cannot occur simultaneously. If that assumption is right, then: first, notice that it implies that $p \leq 1/3$, because we have
\begin{align*}& P(A \cup B \cup C)\\ = \ & P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C) \\
= \ & P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 3p
\end{align*}
and it would certainly be a contradiction if $3p > 1$. If that's right, then $X$ is either $0$ or $1$. The calculation above would imply that $X = 1$ with probability $3p$, and consequently that $X = 0$ with probability $1-3p$.

Comment: I think you meant your last sentence to say "$X=0$ with probability $1-3p.$

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

(I'm posting this because I wrote it before reading Aaron Montgomery's answer. Perhaps it can be of some benefit.)

Here's my interpretation of your question ...

1. Since you refer to "each iteration", it seems that repeated trials are involved, each trial having its outcome in some set (call it $\Omega$) of all possible trial-outcomes. Presumably, your sets $A,B,C,$ are subsets of $\Omega$.
2. Since you "think that only one of them can occur in each iteration", I will assume that $A,B,C$ are pairwise disjoint. Thus, in each trial, we know that exactly one of the following *four* events occurs: $A\bar{B}\bar{C}\,(=A)$, $\bar{A}B\bar{C}\,(=B)$, $\bar{A}\bar{B}C\,(=C)$, or $\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}$. 
   (Overbar denotes complement.)

   **NB**: $1=P(\Omega)=P(A\bar{B}\bar{C}\cup \bar{A}B\bar{C}\cup \bar{A}\bar{B}C\cup \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C})\\=3p + P(\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}),$ hence $P(\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C})=1-3p.$
3. "Let $X$ be the number of events that occurred among the three. What is the distribution of $X$ when every two events are foreign to each other?" The assumption is that "foreign to each other" means "pairwise disjoint", i.e. mutually exclusive; so $X$ is $0$ with probability $1-3p$, and $X$ is $1$ with probability $3p$.

$\therefore\quad X$ has a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with parameter $3p$: $P(X=1) = 3p,\, P(X=0) = 1-3p.$

Comment: If p=0.5 for example, how is it possible?

Comment: @Eusebius - All probabilities must be in the interval $[0,1]$, so this must be true for $P(X=1) = 3p$ and for $P(X=0) = 1-3p$; hence it must be the case that $0\le p\le \frac{1}{3}$ (as Aaron Montgomery also pointed out).